# Python TripleDES decryption

Tags: python, vb.net, arrays, tripledes

I'm trying to decrypt a string in python encrypted using 3DES. It is encrypted by VB.net by my formal mate. I have no idea what is going on. The partial code in VB.net is

```
Private key() As Byte = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24}
Private iv() As Byte = {65, 110, 68, 26, 69, 178, 200, 219}
Private objTripleDES As New clsTripleDES(key, iv)
```

The code is similar is to https://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=1564&lngWId=10

Is it possible  to decrypt in python? Do I need to use bytearray?

Comment: Take a look on [pyDes lib](http://twhiteman.netfirms.com/des.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import DES3

key = [
     1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8, 
     9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
     17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24
]

iv = [65, 110, 68, 26, 69, 178, 200, 219]

keyStr = ""
ivStr = ""

for i in key: 
    keyStr += chr(i)

for i in iv: 
    ivStr += chr(i)

encr = DES3.new(keyStr, DES3.MODE_CBC, ivStr)
decr = DES3.new(keyStr, DES3.MODE_CBC, ivStr)

#Outputs "1234567891234567"
print decr.decrypt(encr.encrypt("1234567891234567"))
```

You should investigate what mode was used for encryption in VB code. CBC is the default mode, according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.mode(v=vs.110).aspx), but you can't be sure.
See [this](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/2.6/) when you figure out what mode was used.